# Python 3.6 Lambda code error for os.environ variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-lambda

```
try :
        sf =                       Salesforce(username = sfdc_username, 
                                   password = sfdc_password, 
                                   security_token = sfdc_security_token, 
                                   instance_url = sfdc_salesforce_instance_url, 
                                   domain = sfdc_sandbox)
        print('salesforce login good')
    except (SalesforceGeneralError, 
            SalesforceMoreThanOneRecord, 
            SalesforceMalformedRequest, 
            SalesforceExpiredSession, 
            SalesforceRefusedRequest, 
            SalesforceResourceNotFound) as e :
        print(e.content[0]['message'])
        sys.exit(1)
```

this portion of code on lambda is failing with the error:

```
a bytes-like object is required, not 'str': TypeError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/sfdc_etl/bin/sfdc_etl.py", line 80, in lambda_handler
    domain = sfdc_sandbox)
  File "/var/task/sfdc_etl/lib/python3.6/site-packages/simple_salesforce/api.py", line 146, in __init__
    domain=self.domain)
  File "/var/task/sfdc_etl/lib/python3.6/site-packages/simple_salesforce/login.py", line 80, in SalesforceLogin
    username = escape(username)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/html/__init__.py", line 19, in escape
    s = s.replace("&", "&amp;") # Must be done first!
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

When I move this code to my test environment on an EC2 amazon linux and set the sfdc_sandox to 'test' in line, it works with no issues. I tried using os.environb["L_SFDC_SANDBOX"] and os.environ["L_SFDC_SANDBOX"].encode('utf8'), but that also did not help as it gave the same error.  How do I fix the type error when I pull in this variable in Lambda?

Here is the entire script, maybe the error isn't because of that specific piece of code even though it seems like it is.

```
import os
import sys

# this adds the parent directory of bin so we can find the  module
parent_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.path.pardir))
sys.path.append(parent_dir)
#This addes venv lib/python2.7/site-packages/ to the search path
mod_path = os.path.abspath(parent_dir+"/lib/python"+str(sys.version_info[0])+"."+str(sys.version_info[1])+"/site-packages/")
sys.path.append(mod_path)

from awsmgr.awsmgr import S3Helper
from base64 import b64decode
import boto3
from collections import OrderedDict
import datetime
from dateutil.parser import parse
import logging
import json
import math
import pandas as pd
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce, SalesforceLogin
from simple_salesforce.exceptions import SalesforceGeneralError, SalesforceMoreThanOneRecord, SalesforceMalformedRequest, SalesforceExpiredSession, SalesforceRefusedRequest, SalesforceResourceNotFound
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import exc

current_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
# Use this one for the parent directory
ENV_ROOT =  os.path.abspath(os.path.join(current_path, os.path.pardir))
# Use this one for the current directory
#ENV_ROOT =  os.path.abspath(os.path.join(current_path))
sys.path.append(ENV_ROOT)

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    ###############################
    # Global Variable Definitions #
    ###############################
    d_parse =                       parse
    TMP_PATH =                      '/tmp'
    igersUser =                     'admin'
    igersPwd =                      boto3.client('kms').decrypt(CiphertextBlob=b64decode(os.environ["RS_PASSWORD"]))['Plaintext']
    igersHost =                     os.environ["RS_HOST"]
    igers =                         create_engine('postgres://{}:{}@{}/ibdrs'.format(igersUser, igersPwd, igersHost), encoding="utf-8")
    igersSchema =                   os.environ["RS_SCHEMA"]
    s3 =                            S3Helper(debug=os.environ["DEBUG"])
    nextObjFile =                   s3.get_s3_file('s3://test-sfdc-sds-team/sfdc-etl-jp-test/sfdc_etl/objects/next_object.txt',os.path.abspath(os.path.join(TMP_PATH,'next_object.txt')))
    s3Destination =                 's3://test-sfdc-sds-team/sfdc-etl-jp-test/sfdc_etl/json/'
    s3Path =                        '{}_json'
    s3NextObjDestination =          's3://test-sfdc-sds-team/sfdc-etl-jp-test/sfdc_etl/objects/{}'
    fileCount =                     1
    sfdc_username =                 os.environ["L_USERNAME"].encode('utf8')
    sfdc_salesforce_instance_url =  os.environ["L_SALESFORCE_INSTANCE_URL"].encode('utf8')    
    sfdc_password =                 boto3.client('kms').decrypt(CiphertextBlob=b64decode(os.environ["L_PASSWORD"]))['Plaintext']
    sfdc_security_token =           boto3.client('kms').decrypt(CiphertextBlob=b64decode(os.environ["L_SECURITY_TOKEN"]))['Plaintext']
    sfdc_sandbox        =           os.environ["L_SFDC_SANDBOX"].encode('utf8')

    print(type(sfdc_username), type(sfdc_password), type(sfdc_security_token), type(sfdc_salesforce_instance_url), type(sfdc_sandbox))
    try :
        sf =                       Salesforce(username = sfdc_username, 
                                   password = sfdc_password, 
                                   security_token = sfdc_security_token, 
                                   instance_url = sfdc_salesforce_instance_url, 
                                   domain = sfdc_sandbox)
        print('salesforce login good')
    except (SalesforceGeneralError, 
            SalesforceMoreThanOneRecord, 
            SalesforceMalformedRequest, 
            SalesforceExpiredSession, 
            SalesforceRefusedRequest, 
            SalesforceResourceNotFound) as e :
        print(e.content[0]['message'])
        sys.exit(1)

    # get nextobj from s3 
    with open(nextObjFile, 'r') as f :
        nextObjItem = f.read().strip().lower()
        nextObj = nextObjItem.lower()

    print('Processing {}'.format(nextObj))

    ######################################################
    # get rs table group permissions, store in dataframe #
    ######################################################
    def rsGetGroupPerms(igers, nextObj) : 
        global groupPerms
        groupPerms = {}
        existingGroupPerms = '''
        SELECT
            namespace, item, type, groname 
        FROM
            (
            SELECT
                use.usename AS subject,
                nsp.nspname AS NAMESPACE,
                cls.relname AS item,
                cls.relkind AS TYPE,
                use2.usename AS OWNER,
                cls.relacl 
            FROM
                pg_user use
                CROSS JOIN pg_class cls
                LEFT JOIN pg_namespace nsp ON cls.relnamespace = nsp.oid
                LEFT JOIN pg_user use2 ON cls.relowner = use2.usesysid 
            WHERE
                cls.relowner = use.usesysid 
                AND nsp.nspname NOT IN ( 'pg_catalog', 'pg_toast', 'information_schema' ) 
                AND nsp.nspname IN ( 'salesforce' ) 
                AND relacl IS NOT NULL 
            ORDER BY
                subject,
                NAMESPACE,
                item 
            )
            JOIN pg_group pu ON array_to_string( relacl, '|' ) LIKE'%%' || pu.groname || '%%'
            WHERE item = '{}'
        '''.format(nextObj)

        groupPerms = pd.read_sql(existingGroupPerms, igers)
        print('got the group permissions')
        return groupPerms

    #####################################################
    # get rs table user permissions, store in dataframe #
    #               NOT CURRENTLY IN USE                #
    #####################################################
    #def rsGetUseerPerms(igers, nextObj) :
    #    existingUserPerms = '''
    #    SELECT * 
    #    FROM 
    #    (
    #    SELECT 
    #        schemaname
    #        ,objectname
    #        ,usename
    #        ,HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usrs.usename, fullobj, 'select') AND has_schema_privilege(usrs.usename, schemaname, 'usage')  AS sel
    #        ,HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usrs.usename, fullobj, 'insert') AND has_schema_privilege(usrs.usename, schemaname, 'usage')  AS ins
    #        ,HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usrs.usename, fullobj, 'update') AND has_schema_privilege(usrs.usename, schemaname, 'usage')  AS upd
    #        ,HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usrs.usename, fullobj, 'delete') AND has_schema_privilege(usrs.usename, schemaname, 'usage')  AS del
    #        ,HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usrs.usename, fullobj, 'references') AND has_schema_privilege(usrs.usename, schemaname, 'usage')  AS ref
    #    FROM
    #        (
    #        SELECT schemaname, 't' AS obj_type, tablename AS objectname, schemaname + '.' + tablename AS fullobj FROM pg_tables
    #        UNION
    #        SELECT schemaname, 'v' AS obj_type, viewname AS objectname, schemaname + '.' + viewname AS fullobj FROM pg_views
    #        ) AS objs
    #        ,(SELECT * FROM pg_user) AS usrs
    #    ORDER BY fullobj
    #    )
    #    WHERE (sel = true or ins = true or upd = true or del = true or ref = true)
    #    and objectname = '{}'
    #    '''.format(nextObj)
    #    
    #    userPerms = pd.read_sql_query(existingUserPerms, igers)
    #    return userPerms

    ####################################################
    # Connect to Salesforce, Query JSON, and Copy to S3#
    ####################################################
    def sfToS3(fileCount, sf, nextObj) :
        # Initiate list for returned data
        pulls = []

        # Pull initial Query
        sfobject = sf.restful('sobjects/{}/describe/'.format(nextObj), params=None)        
        fields_list = [record['name'] for record in sfobject['fields']]
        initialQuery = sf.query("SELECT {} FROM {}".format(','.join(fields_list),nextObj))
        #Send a single file or the first file to S3
        data = initialQuery['records']
        try :
            send_temp_jsonl_to_s3(data, nextObj, s3, s3Destination, fileCount, s3Path)

            # Append initial query data to pulls
            if 'nextRecordsUrl' in initialQuery :
                pulls.append(initialQuery['nextRecordsUrl'])
                nextChunk = initialQuery['nextRecordsUrl']
                nextQuery = sf.query_more(nextChunk,True)
                if 'nextRecordsUrl' in nextQuery :
                    pulls.append(nextQuery['nextRecordsUrl'])
                    x = True         
                    fileCount = 2

                    while x == True:
                        try:                       
                            # set up while loop to re-query salesforce until returned
                            # query does not have a 'nextRecordsUrl' return value
                            # Query new 'nextRecordsUrl'
                            nextQuery = sf.query_more(nextQuery['nextRecordsUrl'],True)

                            # append new query to pulls
                            pulls.append(nextQuery['nextRecordsUrl'])
                        except: # This triggers when nextQuery['nextRecordsUrl'] does not exist
                            # set x to False to end loop
                            x = False 

            #if there was a follow on set of records, query it and add to S3      
            if len(pulls) >= 1 :
                for i in range(len(pulls)) :
                    data = sf.query_more(str(pulls[i].split('/')[5]))['records']

                    send_temp_jsonl_to_s3(data, nextObj, s3, s3Destination, fileCount, s3Path)

                    fileCount += 1
            print('completed sending JSON files to S3')
        except :
            print('Salesforce Object Empty, ending execution')
            updateNextObj(nextObj, s3NextObjDestination)
            sys.exit(1)

    ####################
    #   JSONL to S3    #
    ####################
    def send_temp_jsonl_to_s3(data, nextObj, s3, s3Destination, fileCount, s3Path) :
        fileName = '{}_file{}.json'
        localFilePath ='/tmp/'    

        for element in data :

            item = data.pop()
            item.pop('attributes', None)

            tempdict = OrderedDict({})
            for k,v in item.items() :
                if 'date' in k.lower() or 'stamp' in k.lower() :
                    if not v is None :
                        d = d_parse(v)
                        v = d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S')
                        tempdict[k.lower()] = v
                else :
                    tempdict[k.lower()] = v

                with open(localFilePath+fileName.format(nextObj,fileCount), 'a') as outfile :
                    outfile.write(json.dumps(tempdict))
                    outfile.write('\n')

        s3.put_s3_file_datedpath(localFilePath+fileName.format(nextObj,fileCount),s3Destination+s3Path.format(nextObj))
        os.remove(localFilePath+fileName.format(nextObj,fileCount))

    #################################################
    #   maps SFDC type to SQL type - used for ddl   #
    #################################################
    def map_data_type(sfdc_type, length):
            """
            Definition to map Salesforce datatype to Redshift datatype.
            """
            __MULTIPLIER = 1.3 # may not be Zero!

            if length == 0:
                length = 1092
            if length == 4095:
                length = 15000
            if length > 65535:
                length = 65534

            if sfdc_type == u'boolean':
               return u'varchar(5)'
            elif  sfdc_type == u'date':
               return u'timestamp'
            elif sfdc_type == u'datetime':
               return  u'timestamp'
            elif sfdc_type == u'currency':
               return  u'decimal(38,6)'
            elif sfdc_type == u'double':
               return  u'decimal(38,6)'
            elif sfdc_type == u'int':
               return  u'numeric(10)'
            elif sfdc_type == u'picklist':
               return  u'varchar({})'.format(length)
            elif sfdc_type == u'id':
               return  u'varchar({})'.format(length)
            elif sfdc_type == u'reference':
               return  u'varchar({})'.format(length)
            elif sfdc_type == u'textarea':
                if length >= (65535/length*__MULTIPLIER):
                    return  u'varchar({})'.format(65534)
                else:
                    return  u'varchar({})'.format( math.ceil(length*__MULTIPLIER))
            elif sfdc_type == u'email':
               return  u'varchar({})'.format(length)
            elif sfdc_type == u'phone':
               return  u'varchar({})'.format(length)
            elif sfdc_type == u'url':
               return  u'varchar({})'.format(length)
            elif sfdc_type == u'multipicklist':
               return  u'varchar({})'.format(length)
            elif sfdc_type == u'anyType':
                if length >= 65535:
                    return  u'varchar({})'.format(65534)
                else:
                    return  u'varchar({})'.format(math.ceil(length*__MULTIPLIER))
            elif sfdc_type == u'percent':
               return  u'numeric(38,6)'
            elif sfdc_type == u'combobox':
               return  u'varchar({})'.format(length)
            elif sfdc_type == u'base64':
               return  u'varchar({})'.format(length)
            elif sfdc_type == u'time':
               return  u'varchar(255)'
            elif sfdc_type == u'string':
                if length >= 65535:
                    return  u'varchar({})'.format(65534)
                else:
                    return  u'varchar({})'.format(math.ceil(length*__MULTIPLIER))
            else:
               return  u'varchar(65535)'

    ####################################
    #   Turn SFDC metadata into SQL    #
    ####################################
    def get_ddl(sf, nextObj, igersSchema, col_remove=None):
        md = sf.restful("sobjects/{}/describe/".format(nextObj), params=None)
        target_table=nextObj
        total_field_count = 0
        global ddl_str
        ddl_str = ''

        ddl_str += 'CREATE TABLE '+ igersSchema+"."+target_table +' ('
        for x in md["fields"]:
            #print x["name"]
            if col_remove: 
                if x["name"].lower() in [element.lower() for element in col_remove]:
                    print("Skipping: {}".format(x["name"]))
                    continue
            ddl_str += x["name"] + ' ' + map_data_type(x["type"],x["length"])
            if x["name"] == 'Id':
                 ddl_str += ' NOT NULL DISTKEY'
            ddl_str +=  ","              
            total_field_count = total_field_count + 1
        ddl_str = ddl_str[:-1]
        ddl_str += ')'
        logging.info('DDL Successfully created...')
    #    print("Total Field Count: "+str(total_field_count))
        return ddl_str

    #########################
    # Create Table from DDL, execute the copy query and update permissions #
    #########################
    def rs_operations(ddl_str, groupPerms, igersSchema, nextObj, s3Destination, s3Path, igers) :
        today = datetime.date.today()
        dated_path = today.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
        perms_statement = ''    

        drop_table = '''
            DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {}.{} CASCADE
            '''.format(igersSchema, nextObj)

        loadQuery = '''
            COPY {}.{}
            FROM '{}{}/{}/'
            iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::087024238921:role/LambdaFullAccessRole'
            TRUNCATECOLUMNS
            FORMAT AS JSON 'auto'
        '''.format(igersSchema, nextObj, s3Destination, s3Path.format(nextObj), dated_path)

        grantPerms = '''
        GRANT SELECT ON {}.{} TO GROUP {}
        '''

        with igers.connect() as conn:
            try :
                conn.execute(drop_table)
                print('completed drop table')
                conn.execute(ddl_str)
                print('completed create table')
                conn.execute(loadQuery)
                print('completed load query')
                for row in range(len(groupPerms)) :
                    perms_statement = grantPerms.format(groupPerms['namespace'].iloc[row],groupPerms['item'].iloc[row],groupPerms['groname'].iloc[row])
                    conn.execute(perms_statement)
                print('completed grant group permissions')
                conn.close()
            except exc.SQLAlchemyError as e :
                print(e)  

    ######################################
    # Update Next Object and Write to S3 #
    ######################################
    def updateNextObj(nextObj, s3NextObjDestination) :
        objectsList = []
        objectsFile = s3.get_s3_file('s3://test-sfdc-sds-team/sfdc-etl-jp-test/sfdc_etl/objects/sfdc_etl_objects.txt',os.path.abspath(os.path.join(TMP_PATH,'sfdc_etl_objects.txt')))
        localNobjTempFile = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(TMP_PATH,'next_object.txt'))
        nextObjText = ''

        with open (objectsFile, 'r') as objs :
            for line in objs :
                objectsList.append(line.strip("\n"))

        for i in range(len(objectsList)-1) :
            if objectsList[i].lower() == nextObj :
                nextObjText = objectsList[i+1]
                print(nextObjText)

        with open (localNobjTempFile, 'w') as f :
            f.write(nextObjText)

        s3.put_s3_file(localNobjTempFile,s3NextObjDestination.format('next_object.txt'))
        print('completed Updating the next object')

    ################################################
    #     Test if the object exists and execute    #
    ################################################
    try :
        getattr(sf,nextObj).describe()
    except (SalesforceGeneralError, 
            SalesforceMoreThanOneRecord, 
            SalesforceMalformedRequest, 
            SalesforceExpiredSession, 
            SalesforceRefusedRequest, 
            SalesforceResourceNotFound) as e :
        print(e.content[0]['message'] +', writing next object and ending')
        updateNextObj(nextObj, s3NextObjDestination)
        sys.exit(1)

    rsGetGroupPerms(igers, nextObj)
    sfToS3(fileCount, sf, nextObj)
    get_ddl(sf, nextObj, igersSchema, col_remove=None)
    rs_operations(ddl_str, groupPerms, igersSchema, nextObj, s3Destination, s3Path, igers)
    updateNextObj(nextObj, s3NextObjDestination)
```

Comment: just put in `print(type(sfdc_sandbox))` and it says <class 'bytes'> so I am really at a loss as to the problem.

Comment: It seems that `sandbox` kwarg is already deprecated (https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce/blob/master/simple_salesforce/login.py#L38), could you try using the `domain` kwarg instead?

Comment: yea I was using that before, let me switch back and try that.

Comment: From the traceback I can see the error itself is with the password, could you print out the `sfdc_password` type (i.e. `print(type(sfdc_password))`). It looks like the `html.escape` (https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce/blob/master/simple_salesforce/login.py#L81) function is receiving the wrong type.

Comment: I updated to domain, same issue.  as for the print type: `print(type(sfdc_username), type(sfdc_password), type(sfdc_security_token), type(sfdc_salesforce_instance_url), type(sfdc_sandbox))` yields the following `<class 'bytes'> <class 'bytes'> <class 'bytes'> <class 'bytes'> <class 'bytes'>`

Comment: Try `print(">>>", escape(str(b"<h2>Hello World&Hello Python</h2>"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the following line

```
sfdc_password = boto3.client('kms').decrypt(CiphertextBlob=b64decode(os.environ["L_PASSWORD"]))['Plaintext']
```

is returning a bytes object, and in the other hand, the `Salesforce` class expects a string.

Solution:

---

```
try :
    sf = Salesforce(username=sfdc_username,
                    password=sfdc_password.decode("utf-8"),
                    security_token=sfdc_security_token,
                    instance_url=sfdc_salesforce_instance_url,
                    domain=sfdc_sandbox)
    print('salesforce login good')
```

Note that the `sfdc_password` variable is being converted to string using the `.decode` bytes method

Comment: Slack, that got me thinking about the issue more.  so it was the password and security token which were passing in from the boto3 decode as bytes and not str.

Comment: I'm glad to help :)